# Allow anonymous access to Content and Script folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication

I am building a ASP.NET MVC 2 website that uses Forms authentication. Now I want to allow unauthenticated users access to the Scripts and Content folders, so the stylesheets and images will load. However, it does not work. From what I found on Google, this should work:

```
<location allowOverride="false" path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location allowOverride="false" path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

It does not work in ASP.NET MVC 2 on IIS (win7). The stylesheet and javascript requests are redirected to Account/LogOn. How do I fix this?

Update: Anonymous Authentication is enabled in IIS. So is forms authentication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the Authorization tags in the web.config. Use the Authorization attribute in your Controllers (or Actions).

Comment: When I create a new mvc 2 application, visual studio automatically adds <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication> to the web.config. Should I remove this?

Comment: No, don't remove the Authentication tags. It's the Authorization tags that shouldn't be used in the web.config in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: when i leave the authentication tags and remove the authorization tags, I get an error that the anonoymous user is not allowed access to the ACL or something, even when I have given everyone and anonoymous full access in Windows explorer.

Comment: I'm not sure what has changed, but for some reason it works now.